# Run multiple c++ program using python script

Tags: python

I need to execute multiple c++ programs through my python script. These c++ programs are acting like clients and server. So I need to run them simultaneously. But the script was waiting to end the first c++ program to start next.
script which I wrote given below:

```
import subprocess
import os
os.chdir("/home/My_Work/pgm_1")
cmd="gnome-terminal -e 'bash -c make;./pgm_1 exec bash'"
subprocess.Popen(cmd,shell=True)//control comes till here
os.chdir("/home/My_Work/pgm_2")
cmd2="gnome-terminal -e 'bash -c make;./pgm_2 exec bash'"
subprocess.Popen(cmd2,shell=True)
```

Please help me to solve this issue

Comment: I don't understand what you want...

Comment: add print statements to check when the program gets to each step, based on the code you wrote it should be simultaneous.

Comment: This program doesn't wait for either program to finish. In fact, it exits and likely you won't even see the second command. When you say "control comes to here" ... how do you know?

Comment: Could you write up an example we can all try? maybe just sleep a bit instead of running a command and no changing to directories and running commands we don't have?

Comment: I removed the chdirs and replaced the commands with `"gnome-terminal -e 'sleep 5'"`. I got two new terminal windows which exited after 5 seconds. So, cannot reproduce.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments in your post, your code does not appear to function. However, when you get it to run, you can use this strategy to manage running both programs simultaneously. I doubt the code below will work if your original code does not; thus it is meant as a GUIDE for multithreading if you choose to use it.

To run functions simultaneously, use multithreading.

```
# import the necessary modules
import thread

# define the functions that will manage the two programs
def prog1():
    print 'Program 1 running'
    os.chdir("/home/My_Work/pgm_1")
    cmd="gnome-terminal -e 'bash -c make;./pgm_1 exec bash'"
    subprocess.Popen(cmd,shell=True)//control comes till here

def prog2():
    print 'Program 2 running!'
    os.chdir("/home/My_Work/pgm_2")
    cmd2="gnome-terminal -e 'bash -c make;./pgm_2 exec bash'"
    subprocess.Popen(cmd2,shell=True)

# call the threads simultaneously
try:
    thread.start_new_thread(prog1)
    thread.start_new_thread(prog2)
except: # i don't know what kind of error to expect here, it is usually not a good idea to leave this blank!
    print 'Threads failed to start!'

# keeps the program running
while 1:
    pass
```

[Source](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_multithreading.htm)